# Python: Finding connected components in a graph presented as edge lists

Tags: python, algorithm, search, graph, networkx

I have an edge list in the form

```
start | end
 a       c
 b       d
 e       b
```

I have tens of millions of edges (approx 30 million) and I'm not able to read  in the entire graph into memory - at least not using a library like networkx which is a bit memory intensive.

My goal is to find all connected components in the graph represented by that list that contain less than `x` number of nodes.

For example, I want to get all connected components with less than `x=30` nodes. But I don't want to do this by building the entire graph and then doing a search for connected components (e.g. calling this networkx command: `nx.connected_component_subgraphs(nxg)`).

Is there a way I can search for connected components just using the edge list file and without having to build the entire graph?

Additional info: The node names are strings of length 10-20 asci values.

Comment: How long are your node names? Assuming they are encoded as integers, an array of them would only take about 500 MB. I’d use pandas to read the file as csv, set the first column as sorted index and implement a breadth-first search from scratch. This can probably made quite speedy with clever use of loc.

Comment: I am using pandas to read in the file. But the node names are strings of length 10-20 asci values. I will update the post with this info.

Comment: Do you have any code samples for the breadth first search for CCs from edge lists? @AlexNe

Comment: the important info is, that you can fit everything into memory. If the first column is index, Breadth-first search can be relatively easily implemented using df.loc[second_column] in a while loop, I believe.

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t have any for pandas. If I have time later, I’ll write a prototype.

Comment: Are the characters *any* ASCII characters, or are they in a subset of ASCII?

Comment: I would first remap all unique strings to contiguous integers. Then the data set hopefully fits more easily into memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would first need to reduce the footprint of your data by assigning shorter identifiers for your nodes. You could write a mapping between those shorter identifiers and original names to another file, so you can translate any solution to those names after running an algorithm.

Assuming you have short enough identifiers for your nodes, you could load everything in memory, in a dictionary keyed by node identifiers.

Then use the Union-Find structure & algorithm to identify the connected components.

Finally filter those by the maximum size they are allowed to have.

There are some libraries out there which provide Union-Find implementations, which could provide better performance. Here is a simple implementation of Union-Find:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.parent = self
        self.size = 1

class UnionFind(dict):
    def find(self, key):
        node = self.get(key, None)
        if node is None:
            node = self[key] = Node(key)
        else:
            while node.parent != node: 
                # walk up & perform path compression
                node.parent, node = node.parent.parent, node.parent
        return node

    def union(self, key_a, key_b):
        node_a = self.find(key_a)
        node_b = self.find(key_b)
        if node_a != node_b:  # disjoint? -> join!
            if node_a.size < node_b.size:
                node_a.parent = node_b
                node_b.size += node_a.size
            else:
                node_b.parent = node_a
                node_a.size += node_b.size
```

Then, the following function would load that structure from an iterator, and return the components whose sizes meet the requirement:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def find_components(line_iterator, max_size):
    forest = UnionFind()

    for line in line_iterator:
        forest.union(*line.split())

    result = defaultdict(list)
    for key in forest.keys():
        root = forest.find(key)
        if root.size <= max_size:
            result[root.key].append(key)

    return list(result.values())
```

Here is a demo for the following graph:

[image]

```
data = """x d
c j
i e
f x
n z
a u
g r
w x
p l
u o
m g
k s
t q
y l
h m
n b
k v
e u
i o
r m
n c
x q
f q
j l
s v"""

results = find_components(data.splitlines(), 5)
print(results)
```

The output for this demo is:

```
[['i', 'e', 'a', 'u', 'o'], ['g', 'r', 'm', 'h'], ['k', 's', 'v']]
```